# How to wait until keyboard is raised in flutter?

Tags: flutter, scroll, keyboard, keyboard-events, scrolltoindex

I'm using the scroll to index
library [here](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index)

(When I press the reply button of the comment, the scroll is moved to the comment area where I pressed the reply button.)

Pressing the reply button activates the keyboard, which becomes strange because it moves before the keyboard rises.

I want to wait for the keyboard to come up when I press the button and let it move when it comes up.

I've tried hasFocus, but it seems to be a solution that has nothing to do with this problem.

**flutter_keyboard_visibility** is same.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fabiancrx/47662fda1495ef2172f53f5b98974f04) to see if it fits your use case